# how to use web browser in windows 8 apps using c#

Tags: windows-8

i am beginner in windows 8 Metro apps, i just wanted to know how to use web browser in windows 8 apps using c# like in windows phone 7 we use (WebBrowserTask)object.show()

Comment: This is not a Windows-phone-7 question. Please do not use tags like that as it is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [WebView class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) and the [XAML WebView Control sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7)

Comment: which method should we use to  display a specified  web page?

Comment: did you run the sample?  It does exactly that and you should be able to abstract that code to your needs.  Do be aware that a Windows 8 app does need to do more than be a container for a web page to pass certification.